# Web API model validation based on paramters

Tags: c#, api, rest, web

I have API like this , what i want his 
When i call   with out any parameters 
`http//localhostcustomer/employes/`   it should return 
`StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)`

And if pass with invalid parameters `http//localhostcustomer/employes/customerid=abcsd&employedid=yyyy`  it should return 
`StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);`

how to do model validation for this

```
[Route("customer/employes")]
Public class testcontroller : controller

public List<Emplyees> get( [Required]int customerid, [Required]int employedid)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
     return OK
  else
     StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
}
```

Comment: kindly pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), to make your question easier to read.

Comment: You can use [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and check request before that running on controller

Answer (score 0):

since you dont actually pas a model u dont realy get to place the validation on something since u just pass loose parameters.

u could create a method or class that validates your input parameters like

```
IsValid(CustomerId,EmployedId) return Ok()
```

Or modify the current ModelState.IsValid so

```
ModelState.IsValid(CustomerId,EmployedId) return Ok()
```

Since it seems that your are trying to create a Get request with Required parameters it might be interesting to format this as a proper REST call so your path looks like
**/customer/[CustomerId]/employes/[employedId]**

Answer (score 0):

#### Without parameters - Not Found

If you haven't registered (either explicitly or implicitly via attributes) the route `/employees` then ASP.NET will not find a handler for that request that's why by default it will return with 404.

#### With malformed parameters - Bad Request

That's a bit more tricky. Whenever you have a route with parameters then you can define their types as well. By default if the request contains the route parameter, which can't be converted into that specific type then ASP.NET will not call your handler, rather than it will try to find a better route for that.

Request: `/employees/123info`

```
[Route("customer/employees")]
public List<Employee> Get( [Required]int someParameter) {
```

If you want to catch malformed requests as well, then you have to use `string` parameters and try to apply the conversion logic manually:

```
[Route("customer/employees")]
public IActionResult Get(string someParameter) {
  bool isItAValidParameter = int.TryParse(someParameter, out var validParameter):
  if (!isItAValidParameter)
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a model as your parameter, hence validating a model makes no sense. You need to validate your loose parameters explicitly. 
 In case of invalid parameters:

 Request: `/employes/customerid=abcsd&employedid=yyyy`

 By default, the api will return status 400 - Bad Request Error.

In case of without any parameters:

 you will get HTTP ERROR 404 - Page can't be found

---

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at **FluentValidation**, which is a popular .NET library for building strongly-typed validation rules.

You can create a custom validator that checks your controller method parameters and that creates a response accordingly.

Something along the lines of:

```
var validator = new CustomerEmployeeValidator();
var validation = validator.Validate(someparameter);
if (!validation.IsValid)
   return BadRequest(validation.Errors);
```

On how to create the validator, you should look into:
https://fluentvalidation.net/

As a side note, when the input parameter is incorrect, you should always return a BadRequest StatusCode instead of a NotFound StatusCode.

A NotFound StatusCode is typically used when you are searching for specific data externally, and is not found in that repository.